# WooCommerce CSV files

Tags: wordpress, file, csv, woocommerce

Have just finished adding all of my products onto woocommerce and have only just realized that my supplier has a CSV file available for the products.
Having never worked with CSV files before I am not sure if it is still worth importing this file or will this mess up the work I have already done? Now I have manually added all products and descriptions all I really need it for is to update current stock status.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is exporting your products from WooCommerce ( product listing ), compare and adjust this CSV sheet with your supplier's CSV sheet (Adding, removing, changing data) and then import the sheet back to WooCommerce